# Finding Max Number in an Array C Programming

Tags: c

I am trying to find the max number in an array. I have created a function and I am using the following code:

```
int maxValue( int myArray [], int size)
{
    int i, maxValue;
    maxValue=myArray[0];

    //find the largest no
    for (i=0;i)
        {
        if (myArray[i]>maxValue)
        maxValue=myArray[i];
        }   
        return maxValue;
}
```

However I get a syntax error before `)` token. What am I doing wrong and am I even doing this right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your `for`loop in broken - check out any book or online tutorial on C for the correct syntax

Comment: @hollerTrain: Did you get my code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920644/c-compare-numbers/32920851#32920851 and twisted it somehow ?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must pass a valid array with at least one member to this function:

```
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

int
maxValue(int myArray[], size_t size) {
    /* enforce the contract */
    assert(myArray && size);
    size_t i;
    int maxValue = myArray[0];

    for (i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if ( myArray[i] > maxValue ) {
            maxValue = myArray[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}

int
main(void) {
    int i;
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *y = malloc(10 * sizeof(*y));

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        y[i] = rand();
    }

    printf("Max of x is %d\n", maxValue(x, sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])));
    printf("Max of y is %d\n", maxValue(y, 10));

    return 0;
}
```

By definition, the size of an array cannot be negative. The appropriate variable for array sizes in C is `size_t`, use it.

Your `for` loop can start with the second element of the array, because you have already initialized `maxValue` with the first element.

Comment: this is perfect! i assume i just do the opposite if i want to find the lowest number in an array?

Comment: @HollerTrain: `if( myArray[i] < minValue )`

Comment: Note that this assumes your array has at least one element: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: Why not i++ or ++i instead of i += 1?

Comment: @Nate Kohl - That's in GNU C, not ISO/ANSI C (even C99). It's a nonstandard extension and therefore Sinan's code doesn't need to account for it.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Thank you ;-) @Jonathan Leffler: No particular reason.

Comment: @Nate Kohl, Chris Lutz:  In an argument list, `int myArray[]` is effectively the same as `int * myArray`.  The only useful question is whether to test if a null pointer is passed in.

Comment: @David - I know, but @Nate was saying that you could pass an `int Array[0]` variable as a parameter, which would break this code because this code assumes (as it should) that any array(/pointer) passed has at least one element.

Answer (score 5):

A for loop has three parts:

```
for (initializer; should-continue; next-step)
```

A for loop is equivalent to:

```
initializer;
while (should-continue)
{
    /* body of the for */
    next-step;
}
```

So the correct code is:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
```

Comment: what you said about the three parts is very information. thanks for this tip!

Comment: @R Samuel: I'd change "should-continue" to "termination condition", as that's what it is; it's the condition that terminates the loop.

Answer (score 1):

the paren after the for seems to be missing some contents.

normally it should be something like

```
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

include:

```
void main()
{
  int a[50], size, v, bigv;
  printf("\nEnter %d elements in to the array: ");

  for (v=0; v<10; v++)
    scanf("%d", &a[v]);

  bigv = a[0];

  for (v=1; v<10; v++)
  {
    if(bigv < a[v])
      bigv = a[v];
  }

  printf("\nBiggest: %d", bigv);
  getch();
}
```