# Comparing the min and max of n amount of array lists to get and overall min and max

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I need to get an overall min and max out of a set of arraylists. each arraylist is a student's 5 grades.

The amount of students and the grades entered (done in static void main):

```
Console.WriteLine("Input the number of students: ");
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Student[] students = new Student[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    students[i] = new Student();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Enter grade {j} for student {i}: ");
        double grade = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        students[i].addGrade(grade);
    }
}
```

The arrayList of grades is created in a Student class:

```
private ArrayList grades;

public Student()
{
    grades = new ArrayList();
}

public void addGrade(double val)
{
    grades.Add(val);
}
```

Then the min and max of each student is worked out using sort in a getMin and a getMax function respectively. These functions sit in a Student class:

```
public object getMax()
{
    ArrayList sortArrayList = grades;
    sortArrayList.Sort();
    sortArrayList.Reverse();

    var max = sortArrayList[0];

    return max;
}

public object getMin()
{
    ArrayList sortArrayList = grades;
    sortArrayList.Sort();

    var min = sortArrayList[0];

    return min;
}
```

I was told to iterate through each and extract the min and max for each and then compare them. I have gotten the min and max for each but to compare the arrayLists' min and max values is where I am having a logical block.

Comment: Using arraylist is discouraged in favor of list<T>, btw.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but does that make it easier to compare the lists' min's and max's. Also could you maybe tell me why I was downvoted? Am I not specific enough?

Comment: I just realised that my previous comment could've come across in an offensive manner, which it wasn't inteded to.

Comment: No offense taken here and no, not my downvote. List<T> has many Linq goodies built-in; e.g.: Min and Max and then some functions. But as I avoid ArrayList I can't comment or compare with any amount of competence.

Comment: Here is example of how to find maximum from array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690428/finding-max-number-in-an-array-c-programming it is in C but you just need to have the same logic in C#. Logic is inside for loop.

Comment: This code is extremely inefficient. There is no need to sort a list to find its minimum, and then sorting it again in the opposite direction just the find the maximum. If you have it already sorted why not just return the last element for the max value. Also, there is no need to do an expensive operation like sorting at all just to find the min and max. You just need to initialize a min variable with the highest and the max variable with the lowest possible value, iterate over the list and compare if the current element is smaller than min or higher than max and update min and max accordingly.

Comment: @JustinRobert TaW is right. ArrayList is an outdated list structure of .NET 1 before type-safe lists like List<> were introduced. You can see that ArrayList is bad as it forces you to return object (see your getMin and getMax methods) instead of the proper list element type which you would then need to cast to your proper type. ArrayList also permits to insert unrelated objects of a different type by accident. Finally, with List<> you can use LINQ which already provides functions for Min and Max.

Answer (score 0):

**I am keeping this answer open because of OP's recommendation.**

I would suggest `List<Student>` and grades to `List<int>` or `List<double>`, using LINQ:

Max grade per student:

```
grades.Max();
```

you can let `Student.getMax()` return that single line.

Overall max:

```
var overallMax = students.OrderByDescending(st=> st.getMax())
                 .First().getMax();
```

For overall min:

in `Student.getMin()` just return `grades.Min()`

Then

```
var overallMin = students.OrderByAscending(st=> st.getMin())
                 .First().getMin();
```

Comment: So then this rules out the getMin and getMax functions, i would assume. Or rather I replace the code in the functions with their respective LINQ functions.

Comment: Inside Student getMax() just 1 line: `return grades.Max();` (and Min() for getMin() )

Comment: Also try without `.Select(...)` . Let me know if it works.

Comment: It's giving me an error saying `'ArrayList' does not constain a definition for 'Min'`

Comment: I have left out the `grades.Max()` and `.Min()` since it was giving me an error. I kept the orginial code inside the functions and just used the overall max and min lines you posted. Now if the `max` is located the program finds the `min` that `arraylist` where the `max` was located.

Comment: This code only works if he would use List<Student> which implements IEnumerable<Student> which is required for LINQ and LINQ methods like Min and Max.

Comment: Array.Max() exists. Likewise array_of_students.OfType<Student>().ToList();

Comment: @JustinRobert Well ok then glad it helped!

Comment: I did change the `arrayLists` to `List<double> grades;` and `List<Student>`

Comment: @JustinRobert Good choice. Now you can use grades.Max() inside getMax()

Comment: Please explain the Select function and how I am supposed to be using it. Because I try and I keep getting errors

Comment: if you have students as `List<Student>` then try without Select. and do directly .OrderBy

Comment: I forgot to mention that when I tried `List<Student>` I got a whole bunch of errors. across my main class.

Comment: @JustinRobert Well, since the downvote, I assume I was not very helpful. Sorry about that. Good luck with your code

Comment: @Attersson I don't know who that was but I certainly did not downvote it. You steered me in the right direction. I have now successfully been able to get the overallMax and overallMin

Comment: Ah ok great then :)

Comment: @JustinRobert Is it ok for you if I delete this answer?

Comment: You can, though it did help me to get on the right path, so it may help others who are as logically challenged as I am XD

Comment: Since you think so, I will keep it open. As of now, the answer only has 1 downvote. If it worsens I will close it.