# Finding the index of largest number

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to find the index of largest element in a given array in C .

I have tried insertion sort algorithm to determine the largest number in array after that I compared largest value with my all previous array's element and It did not work.

```
void insertion_array(float array[], int n) //* insertion algorithm*//
{
    int i = 1, j;
    float x;

    for (; i < n; i++) {
        x = array[i];
        j = i - 1;

        while ((j >= 0) && (array[j] > x)) {

            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j = j - 1;

        }
        array[j + 1] = x;
    }
}

uint8_t Largest_Number_Finder(float arr[], uint8_t n) {
    uint8_t index;
    insertion_array(arr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[n - 1]) {
            index = i;

        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

I expected to take largest number index but Algorithm gives always last elements index. What should I do to make it right?
Edit=What you navigated as duplicate was to find largest element. I am aiming to find the index of largest element in array.

Comment: No sorting needed. Start with the assumption that the first element (index 0) is the largest. Then loop over all elements, and if there's any element larger than the current largest element, save its index, and continue looping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding Max Number in an Array C Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690428/finding-max-number-in-an-array-c-programming)

Comment: I got the idea thanks @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: with some revision It shall help @Renat

Comment: among other issues, your code seems like it might never assign a value to `index`, which could therefore be returned uninitialised, which would be UB

Comment: Indeed: no sorting. Other objections are there is no need to return any index when sorted, and the caller might already have other index markers (such as smallest) which sorting would invalidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As "Some programmer dude" mentioned in the comment, if your purpose is to just find the index of the largest value, you don't need to implement insertion or any other algorithm to sort the array.

You can probably make a function like this.

```
int find_max_value(float array[], int length)
{
    // set the value of index 0 as the "current max value"
    float max_value = array[0];
    // the same goes for the index number
    int max_index = 0;

    // go through the array 
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++)  
    {
        // if the next index's value is greater than the "current max value"
        // update the max_value and max_index
        if(array[i] > max_value)
        {
            max_value = array[i];
            max_index = i;
        }
    }
    return max_index;
}
```

and try calling that `find_max_value()` function with whatever input values, like

```
int result = find_max_value(array1, 10);   // just an example supposing that you have declared an array called "array1" and its length is 10
printf("%d", result);    // see what the return value of the find_max_value() function would be
```

Comment: As I directed to headline of the question I am aiming to find its index not the value. Indeed ıt works with some regulation.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the original question. I've updated my answer accordingly.